# Bash terminal error when using 'unmask' command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Any time i type the 'unmask' command in my bash terminal i get the error below:

'bash: unmask: command not found'

Please, any ideas on how i can solve this problem, I believe 'unmask' is a built in command.

I am using bash --version 5.0.16(1)

Comment: It is not. Perhaps you are thinking of `umask`?

Comment: Note that questions about using standard UNIX tools are generally a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you actually meant `umask`?

Comment: My bad, i totally meant to type 'umask'. Thanks for your observation.